# Mathematica Manipulate: How to extract the values of local variables?

Tags: extract, wolfram-mathematica, local, manipulate

I used random values in Mathematica's Manipulate. Can I get them out from there?

Comment: I do not mean the geometric primitives that Manipulate operates on (which can be extracted using "copy/paste"), but the values of my local variables used inside the Manipulate.

Comment: Please post example `Manipulate` code and explain exactly what you mean by "Can I get them out from there?". Thanks.

Comment: It is kind of too late. In the next code I can simply do this: Manipulate[Column[{My random stuff, Graphics3D[...]}]].